# How to do simple shape drawing in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, draw

I am new to Gtk and want to do simple drawing of shapes like circles and rectangles. I was looking at the [gnome tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/book1.html) and the hello word example. However the curves section is undocumented. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to what should I look at, and maybe if I need to include some other supplementary library to draw?

Comment: You can make of [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) for that, here is a [reference](http://gnomejournal.org/article/34/writing-a-widget-using-cairo-and-gtk28) you can make use of. There should be more info on cairo site & you can make use google :)

Comment: @another.anon.coward thanks. Will I be able to catch events on the shapes made by cairo? - since I will need to develop a diagram program, that is move-able nodes with edges?

Comment: Cairo is a graphics library so as such it will not have any eventing support. You should consider options of using `GtkDrawingArea` to get eventing from `Gtk` or `GooCanvas` as suggested in the posts.

Comment: @mihajlv: would have been nice to select the best answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkDrawingArea.html about the GtkDrawingArea, plus http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html about Gdk-Drawing-Primitives and you are on the go.

You might also go a bit further by using this link and check out Cairo directly http://www.cairographics.org

Comment: You can use Cairo *with* a GtkDrawingArea, I think that's the default behavior in GTK+ 3 (which does all its drawing using Cairo). It's also possible in GTK+ 2.

Comment: Yes you are right, GTK3s **widget-drawing** all depends on Cairo. Is my posting misunderstanding? Maybe i should rewrite a bit to clarify

Comment: @DanielLeschkowski thanks. Will I be able to catch events on the shapes made by cairo? - since I will need to develop a diagram program, that is move-able nodes with edges?

Comment: @mihajlv Yes, read through the GtkDrawingArea manual. And dont forget that the GtkDrawingArea inherits from GtkWidget. http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-events

Answer (score 3):

The preferred drawing API in GTK 2 and 3 is Cairo. But if you need to develop a diagram program, with nodes that can react to events, you will need also to use a canvas, like [GooCanvas](https://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas/).